# Why 1 is bigger than 1 in R?

Tags: r

I've been using R for data manipulating for quite a long time, and recently I found the conditional statement in R is not right based on my data results.
Here is an example of my data set:

```
tail(ncmi[which(ncmi$type=='Above'),])
               p      freq freq.pred  pred.lwr pred.upr  type
OTU328  0.0008791327    1         1 0.7224672        1 Above
OTU81   0.0008872229    1         1 0.7224672        1 Above
OTU2322 0.0008953131    1         1 0.7224672        1 Above
OTU55   0.0009087967    1         1 0.7224672        1 Above
OTU6952 0.0009141902    1         1 0.7224672        1 Above
OTU5350 0.0009249771    1         1 0.7224672        1 Above
```

If the number in freq is bigger than that of pred.upr, then the type is set as 'Above', as you can see, none of these results in freq is bigger than pred.upr, while the data type is set as 'Above'.

The conditional statement in my code is as below:

```
ncmi$type <- ''
for (k in 1:nrow(ncmi)) {
  if(ncmi$freq[k]>ncmi$pred.upr[k]){
    ncmi$type[k] <- 'Above'
  }else if(ncmi$freq[k]<ncmi$pred.lwr[k]){
    ncmi$type[k] <- 'Below'
  }else{
    ncmi$type[k] <- 'Neutral'
  }
}
```

Why would this happen?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging, like printing the values of `ncmi$freq[k]` and `ncmi$pred.upr[k]`?

Comment: *as you can see, none of these results in freq is bigger than pred.upr* This is not clear because of rounding to display the data on screen. For your console input: `data.frame(x=rep(0.99999999, 5), y=1.00000001)` or `D <- data.frame(x=rep(0.99999999, 5), y=1.00000001);
1 - D[1,1];
D[1,2] - 1 `

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: I'm going to guess (since you didn't provide the code) that `pred.upr` is the upper prediction interval endpoint, obtained via an inverse logistic transform. If so, it will be always strictly less than 1 except in extreme cases. Note that asking whether the observed value for a binary response is within the pred interval doesn't make much sense; that approach assumes a continuous response.

Comment: You do not need a for-loop: `ncmi$type <- 'Neutral';
ncmi$type[ncmi$freq > ncmi$pred.upr] <- 'Above';
ncmi$type[ncmi$freq < ncmi$pred.upr] <- 'Below'`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, @GuyIncognito. But the output is all 1:```c(ncmi$freq[which(rownames(ncmi)=='OTU328')],ncmi$pred.upr[which(rownames(ncmi)=='OTU328')])
[1] 1 1```

Comment: Perhaps you are right. @HongOoi

Comment: Thanks @jogo, these code is written a long time a ago, I didn't fully understand the dataframe quite well that time.